# Creating new column based on last line condition

Tags: r

I've downloaded a stock renko based time-series data. Since it is not a regular time-series data, i believe I cannot use `ts` library.

I'm trying to create a column that summarizes consecutive positive/negative renko boxes.

What I have done so far:

```
library(xlsx)

last <- function(arr, line_no, offset) {
    line_no <- max(1, line_no - offset)
    line_no <- min(nrow(arr), line_no)

    arr[arr$idx == line_no,]
}

wdofut <- read.xlsx('~/Documents/tmp/WDOFUT_5R_20171219.xlsx',sheetIndex = 1,header=TRUE)
wdofut <- wdofut[ order(unclass(wdofut[,1])), ]
wdofut$idx <- 1:nrow(wdofut)

wdofut$positive <- wdofut$Abertura < wdofut$Fechamento
wdofut$lpositive <- last(wdofut,wdofut$indice,1)$positive
wdofut$negative <- wdofut$Abertura > wdofut$Fechamento
wdofut$lnegative <- last(wdofut,wdofut$indice,1)$negative
```

After running this code, `lpositive` remains `TRUE` and `lnegative` remains `FALSE` on all lines

```
> cols <- c(7,1,8:11)
> wdofut[c(1:15),cols]
     idx                Data positive lpositive negative lnegative
5454   1 2017-07-05 17:58:59     TRUE      TRUE    FALSE     FALSE
5449   2 2017-07-06 09:00:00     TRUE      TRUE    FALSE     FALSE
5450   3 2017-07-06 09:00:00     TRUE      TRUE    FALSE     FALSE
5451   4 2017-07-06 09:00:00     TRUE      TRUE    FALSE     FALSE
5452   5 2017-07-06 09:00:00     TRUE      TRUE    FALSE     FALSE
5453   6 2017-07-06 09:00:00     TRUE      TRUE    FALSE     FALSE
5448   7 2017-07-06 09:01:00     TRUE      TRUE    FALSE     FALSE
5446   8 2017-07-06 09:01:59     TRUE      TRUE    FALSE     FALSE
5447   9 2017-07-06 09:01:59     TRUE      TRUE    FALSE     FALSE
5445  10 2017-07-06 09:06:00    FALSE      TRUE     TRUE     FALSE
5444  11 2017-07-06 09:14:59     TRUE      TRUE    FALSE     FALSE
5442  12 2017-07-06 09:24:00    FALSE      TRUE     TRUE     FALSE
5443  13 2017-07-06 09:24:00     TRUE      TRUE    FALSE     FALSE
5441  14 2017-07-06 09:36:00    FALSE      TRUE     TRUE     FALSE
5440  15 2017-07-06 09:58:00    FALSE      TRUE     TRUE     FALSE
>
```

However, when call `last` function on R console, it returns correct answer

```
> last(wdofut,11,1)[,cols]
     idx                Data positive lpositive negative lnegative
5445  10 2017-07-06 09:06:00    FALSE      TRUE     TRUE     FALSE
>
```

I observed that lpositive and lnegative values are the same as in line 1, but I can't understand why.

Can you help me figure this out ?

Comment: By "last" do you really mean "previous"?

Comment: `last()` returns the last row of your data.frame (i.e. `wdofut[nrow(wdofut), ]`). I'd consider using `dplyr::lag` along with `mutate` to create your new columns, assuming you do want the previous value.

Comment: Yes. Actually, the last function will retrieve any previous row by the specified offset. Please note that I can't rely on rowname since there is a need to correct the order based on timestamp located on column 1.

Comment: I'll look deep into dlpyr::lag. I only knew stats::lag, which need a time-series in order to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this is what you're trying to do. `lag()` defaults to a single period lag (i.e. the previous value).

```
require(dplyr)

wdofut %>% arrange(Data) %>% mutate(lpositive = ifelse(lag(positive == TRUE),TRUE,FALSE),
lnegative = ifelse(lag(negative == TRUE), TRUE, FALSE))
```